# Issue with sculpting into cylinder

Tags: modeling, sculpting, dynamic-topology

I'm trying to carve into a cylinder for a project due next week, but its not sculpting the way I need it. When I try it just leaves these tiny polygons behind (see image linked)

http://prntscr.com/d2ghhd

I'm not sure why its doing this, any help is appreciated

Comment: I gave you the answer for your question, but what exactly do you want to achieve with this? I bet there is an easier and cleaner way to do that without sculpting.

Comment: I'm trying to make it look like a the metal part on a no. 2 pencil (you know, the part that holds the eraser to the pencil)

Comment: It's not the best way to do that then.I edited the answer to show you how you can do it in more efficient and clean way.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you have Dynotopo enabled in sculpt mode Tools option.It causes generating new geometry each time you use brush. Disable this option to avoid that.[image]

And here is the way, you can make the element you need in much faster and easier way:
[image]

Comment: When I have Dyntopo off, it does nothing. I asked my professor about this and he said it has to be on. When I tried it (with Dyntopo on) on one of the school computers, it worked just fine, but on my PC, it does that.

Comment: Then you had smooth shading probably turn on on your school computer, and didn't see new geometry created during sculpting.

Comment: I see, thank you for the feedback and the tutorial :D